# Can I record a "regular" iOS view with Everyplay?

Tags: everyplay

Can I record a "regular" iOS view with Everyplay SDK. A view that hasn't been done with OpenGLES or with any game framework? Just a view with UILabels, UIButtons etc.

Answer (score 2):

No. Everyplay can only record OpenGL views.